# Could somoneplease explain this portion from Financial Statement Analysis Text by Fridson and Alvarez

Tags: financial-statements

Please excuse my lack of knowledge. But I was reading the above text and couldnt understand the following calculation. Will someone be kind enough to explain this to me??
[image: The relevant portion of the text]

I am unable to understand how to author arrived at the $365 million figure. I was thinking it should be 25% of $1.114 billion which would come to 27,85,00,000

Answer (score 3):

Your text says that the investor expects 25% rate of return (e.g. "interest per year"), and that the company is assumed to be worth 1114 million dollar in 5 years.

That means, the investor can invest 365 million dollar, as in 5 years, it is 365 million dollar * 1.25^5 = 1114 million dollar.